# Best practices for modelling this scenario

Tags: symfony, design-patterns, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I have a class that extends fos_user class from FOSUserBundle.
Every user have some roles. 
If user has role "BASIC" he has a OneToMany relation with entity Entry (one basic user has many entries).
If user has role "MASTER" he has a ManyToMany relation with entity House (many master users have many houses).

I done this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="House", inversedBy="users")
     */
    protected $houses;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entry", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $entries;

}
```

But it doesn't sound fine.

Is there a **design pattern** for this scenario?

Comment: And your question is … ?

Comment: The question would be refactoring as "is there a design pattern for this scenario?".

Comment: A possible pattern would be single table inheritance. When your question gets reopened and you didn’t find a solution in the meantime, I can give you an example.

Comment: Can an user have both roles? If yes, single table inheritance is not the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @lxg wrote a possible pattern is **single table inheritance**.
You can look an example [here](https://www.liip.ch/en/blog/table-inheritance-with-doctrine).